# javabridge setup/installation issue

Tags: java, php, tomcat, php-java-bridge

I am using wamp server 2 and tomcat 7. I put javabridge.war inside webapp directorya and started tomcat. This created javabridge directory inside webapp.

I even copied this javabridge directory to the root directory. However, when I try to use the follwoing example, I get an error:

```
php require_once("java/Java.inc");
echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();
specified resource () has been forbidden.
```

Can someone tell me what mistake did i make in this setup?

Comment: when i try to use the following code as a test.  require_once("http://127.0.0.1:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");

echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties(); then i get the error Warning: require_once(http://127.0.0.1:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp\www\BirtBridgeTest\test.php on line 2

Answer (score 2):

Remember to do all this

```
1. download PHP/Java Bridge(http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/).
2. deploy the Java Bridge on tomcat Server.
3. copy the jar jasper lib, ireport lib and mysql connector j lib in tomcat lib folder
4. restart tomcat server
5. edit php.ini,turn on setting -> allow_url_include = On;
6. restart apache httpd server
```