# PHP JavaBridge ClassNotFoundException - works on my machine, but not on server

Tags: java, php, apache2, tomcat7, php-java-bridge

Linux server with Apache2, Tomcat7, PHP 5.5.10 are all up and running

Got this project where we have a JavaBridge installed for report generation, I have this working like a charm on my windows pc in an xampp environment, but on the server I am getting a ClassNotFoundException.

I can access the JavaBridge directly from the site by:

```
http://mysite:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc
```

However from the PHP I keep getting this error of ClassNotFoundException

```
//getting Java.inc 
//acquired Java.incdisplay 
//java propertiesIn Java.inc
[[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new com.nlrt.reportgenerator.ReportGenerator([o:PhpParserString], [o:PhpParserString], [o:PhpParserString]). 
Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nlrt.reportgenerator.ReportGenerator VM: 1.6.0_27@http://java.sun.com/" at: 
#-32 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)      
#-31 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546) 
#-30 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
#-29 java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266) 
#-28 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518) 
#-27 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445)
#-26 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458) 
#-25 php.java.bridge.Request.handleOneRequest(Request.java:510) 
#-24 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.handleLocalConnection(PhpJavaServlet.java:202) 
#-23 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.handlePut(PhpJavaServlet.java:250)
#-22 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.doPut(PhpJavaServlet.java:261) 
#-21 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644) 
#-20 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) 
#-19 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) 
#-18 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
#-17 php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126) 
#-16 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
#-15 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
#-14 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224) 
#-13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) 
#-12 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) 
#-11 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) #-10 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) #-9 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) #-8 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) #-7 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) #-6 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987) 
#-5 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579) 
#-4 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307) 
#-3 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
#-2 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
#-1 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) 
#0 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/java/Java.inc(232): java_ThrowExceptionProxyFactory->getProxy(1, NULL, 'T', false) 
#1 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/java/Java.inc(360): java_Arg->getResult(false) 
#2 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/java/Java.inc(363): java_Client->getWrappedResult(false) 
#3 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/java/Java.inc(535): java_Client->getInternalResult() 
#4 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/java/Java.inc(1930): java_Client->createObject('com.nlrt.report...', Array) 
#5 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/devicePorts/FileManager.class.php(139): Java->Java('com.nlrt.report...', '372', '/home/dev/publi...', '{"result_id":"4...') 
#6 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/devicePorts/FileManager.class.php(65): FileManager->generateAndStreamPDF('1', '372') 
#7 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/devicePorts/FileManager.class.php(43): FileManager->handleGenerateAndStreamPDF() 
#8 /home/dev/public/sanome.com/public/report_generation/download_pdf.php(76): FileManager->__construct(Array, '1') 
#9 {main}]
//500 Encountered exception while trying to create ReportGenerator
```

The PHP code that is accessing the required resources is as follows:

```
try
{
    // we'll be using JavaBridge
    echo "getting Java.inc";
    require_once('../java/Java.inc');// http://sanome.com:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc
    echo "acquired Java.inc";
    echo "display java properties";
    //echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();
    $reportGenerator = new java("com.nlrt.reportgenerator.ReportGenerator", $st_usage_id, $report_generator_directory, json_encode($results_array));
    echo "created reportGenerator";
}
catch(Exception $exception)
{
   var_dump($exception) ;//$exception;
}
```

The required JAR has been packaged and added to the WEB-INF/lib directory of the JavaBridge.

Also the php.ini file has the config

```
allow_url_include=On
```

I have even followed these steps but I am having no luck.

[javabridge setup/installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160967/javabridge-setup-installation-issue)

From what I have provided can anyone please help me?

Please don't criticize the solution for it was not my design. I am just trying to get it working, while adding to it.

Thank you.

Comment: Bottom line: the JAR isn't in the classpath on the server.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Okay so I have never worked from a server level before. In tomcat7 I placed my JavaBridge Jar. Restarted tomcat, which  unpackaged the JavaBridge. I then went into JavaBridge/WEB-INF/lib and added the JAR which contains the ReportGenerator. I restarted tomcat7 again. I have this working on my windows system but on the server, so far I have not been able to get it to work. Am I missing another location where the JAR should be added?

Comment: Edit: That should read JavaBridge WAR not JAR.

Comment: Just tried manually adding the JARS to the WAR file and restarting tomcat7. Still no success.

Comment: Okay So I just noticed the error changed and I have a version exception since the server is running on JDK1.6 and I am using JDK1.7. Just updating my environment now. :)